# Calculate updated workdays from today

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(C7,TODAY(),$E$2:$E$500)
```

Which I want to calculate the working days from the starting of the month (c7) to present day today. However I am getting a **`#num`** error any suggestions?

Example.

> 6/01/16 - today (6/21/16) = 15

tomorrow

> 6/01/16 - today (6/22/16) = 16

I'm doing a sales per day average that's why I would like it to update based on the date.

[image: The column N is extracted from a database which gives me current sales till this date however I am trying to provide an estimated June Sales thus why I am dividing it by a Networkingdays]

Comment: In `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` the third argument should be the weekend days argument (or you can leave it blank).  Your third argument is the Holidays range.  But that should be giving you a `#VALUE!` result.  The `#NUM!` error means one your  dates  is really out of wack.

Comment: I have used Networkdays.intl because I have set up my own holidays. I have set up what @manish put however any suggestion on how it would recognize the start of a new month. For example July 1 would be a networkdays of 1 however I am still basing it from the June/1 start date

Comment: Take some time to edit your question such a way so that other can understand it easily. It is very confusing. You are referencing **c7** in your formula, but not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in column A and you want result in column B. Place this formula in Cell B2 and drag it down.

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY())
```

Here is the data that I've used.

[image]

- In cell B4, I have added **`+1`** in formula just to show you the result based on tomorrow's date.
- You will need to change the reference.

Comment: this works great, however how would excel know when the next month would start? For example July 1 the Networkdays would be 1

Comment: I am not getting you. You mean if `Dates` as per my data is having July 1 and you want to know working days on July 1? Can you explain?

Comment: Example. My current sales is 500, I am trying to figure out a sales per day average, so I would divide 500/(networkdays(16)). BUT this is only for June, come July 1 the networkdays would be (23) THIS IS INCORRECT. Because July is the start of a new month and it should be networkdays of (1)

Comment: If you'll have **`7/01/2016`** in cell A5 and if you will try to count working days **on** July 1 using my formula, it will give 1 and NOT 23. You can try same way by putting **`=NETWORKDAYS(A5,TODAY()+9)`** in cell B5 and it will give you 1.

Comment: Okay that make sense, but how would excel know when the start of a new month will be since you are referencing the start of June (06/01/2016)

Comment: My formula will calculate based on date from column A as you can see cell A3 have `5/25/2016` and it has calculated working days accordingly. So if you'll put different date in column A than it will calculate as per that date.

Comment: Is there a way to add a formula to column A, so that is knows to switch to the start of a new month? Instead of a hard coded date?

Comment: What do you have in **`c7`** per your formula? You really need to provide some test data.

Comment: I added test data column N is a extracted hard coded value that give me up till today sales however I want to forecast a full month of sales thus dividing it by a sales per day with Networkdays...The question then becomes since my networkdays is being referenced from the start of june 01 come next month july I want it to update automatically to reference the start of july 01 NOT JUNE